# Can I rename a property that already exist and that has values in it?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

Is there a clause in Cypher that would allow me to rename property `o.operating_system` into `o.os`? I already have values assigned to a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, with Cypher/openCypher, you can do this by copying the old property and then removing it. As a concrete example, using the air-routes data set (tested using Amazon Neptune but it should work elsewhere). In this example we change the property called `code` to a new one named `iata`.

```
MATCH (a:airport {code: 'SFO'})
SET a.iata = a.code
REMOVE a.code
RETURN a
```

And we can see the update has worked...

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "a": {
        "~id": "23",
        "~entityType": "node",
        "~labels": [
          "airport"
        ],
        "~properties": {
          "desc": "San Francisco International Airport",
          "lon": -122.375,
          "runways": 4,
          "type": "airport",
          "country": "US",
          "region": "US-CA",
          "lat": 37.6189994812012,
          "iata": "SFO",
          "elev": 13,
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "icao": "KSFO",
          "longest": 11870
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If I've had any relationships do I need to recreate them?

Comment: If you are just updating a node property, any relationships that node has should be unaffected.